# Find two finite abelian groups of same order $G$ and $H$ such that $G \ncong H.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Find two finite abelian groups of same order $G$ and $H$ such that $G \ncong H.$

I found groups $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $V$ (Klein's group) that satisfy it, but would like more examples. I'm trying to use the result that $p$ is a prime number then all group of $p^2$ order is abelian.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\not\cong \mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z$ (for $p=2$ this is your original example).

Answer (score 3):

Any group $G$ of order $p^2$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/p^2\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$. Proving this essentially boils down to two cases.  Either there is an $a\in G$ with $o(a)=p^2$ or $a^p=1$ for all $a\in G$.

Answer (score 1):

For $n\geq 2$, write $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ for the additive group of the field of $n$ elements. Each element in this group has order $p$, and so $\mathbb F_{p^n} \not\cong C_{p^n}$, the cyclic group of $p^n$ elements.

Answer (score 0):

The three abelian groups of order $8$, namely [$G_1$](http://www.ericmoorhouse.org/pub/bol/htmlfiles8/8_1_8_0.html), [$G_2$](http://www.ericmoorhouse.org/pub/bol/htmlfiles8/8_3_8_0.html) and [$G_3$](http://www.ericmoorhouse.org/pub/bol/htmlfiles8/8_7_8_0.html), belong to three different [isotopy](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Isotopy_of_magmas) classes and hence there can't be two of them being isomorphic.

Comment: Hope it helps, despite $8$ is $2^3$, not $p^2$ for any $p$.